# How to apply timeStampingBrokerPlugin only in 1 queue

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to apply a TTL in one of my queue with broker configuration using following plugin : [timeStampingBrokerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html)

It's the first time I have to use plugin, I tried to add the following code into a policyEntry section :

```
<policyEntry queue="test1">
   <plugins>
       <timeStampingBrokerPlugin ttlCeiling="10400" />
    </plugins>
</policyEntry>
```

But the plugins tag is not accepted here. What is the way to apply a plugin only on some queues or topics?

Comment: What is the way to apply a plugin only on some queues or topics? --> not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do so using the default timestamp plugin.  You can of course use the plugin code as a template for writing your own plugin that looks at the message's destination value to see where it's headed and then apply a TTL or whatever based on that or some other criteria.